# Dropdown Menu - Float Values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dropdown with ipywidgets, it needs to return a variable value, this variable value may change depending on other slider input values. When I try to return the variable I get the error: NameError: 'adjustment_one' Not Defined.

```
calculated_area = input_slider / numstorey_input_slider * 0.7
revised_area = input_slider - calculated_area
adjustment_one = revised_area / input_slider
    
location = ipywidgets.Dropdown(   
    options=[('Internal', 1), ('Roof', adjustment_one), ('External', 2) ],
    value=1,
    description='Plant Space Location: ',
)
```

The above method is solved and was an indenting error however I have now found that I can't pass a float value using the ipywidget dropdown. Below is the code - based on what is selected in the drop down this will be mapped to a dataframe as a multiplier. However when I open the excel document it only every returns the value '0'. This value should actually be 0.87 when Roof is selected, and will change depending on slider input values.

```
    calculated_roof_area = gia_input_slider / numstoreys_input_slider * 0.7
    revised_gia_roofinput = gia_input_slider - calculated_roof_area
    gia_adjustment_rooftop = revised_gia_roofinput / gia_input_slider
    
    plantspace = ipywidgets.Dropdown(   
    options=[('Internal', 1), ('Roof', gia_adjustment_rooftop), ('External', 2) ],
    value=1,
    description='Plant Space Location: ',
    )
    
    print(plantspace)  
    
    df = pd.read_excel(r'dataframe_final.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
        
    # below recalculates the adjusted qty when the slider position changes
    
    multipliers = {
        'Building Footprint Factor': bldg_footprint_factor,
        'CAT A Fitout Yes / No': fitout_cat_dropdown,
        'GIA Factor': gia_factor,
        'GIA Adjustment - Rooftop': plantspace_dropdown
    }

    df['QP1 Multiplier'] = df['QP1'].map(multipliers)
    df['QP2 Multiplier'] = df['QP2'].map(multipliers)
    df['QP3 Multiplier'] = df['QP3'].map(multipliers)
    df['QP4 Multiplier'] = df['QP4'].map(multipliers)
    df['QP5 Multiplier'] = df['QP5'].map(multipliers)
    df['QP6 Multiplier'] = df['QP6'].map(multipliers)
    df['QP7 Multiplier'] = df['QP7'].map(multipliers)
    df['QP8 Multiplier'] = df['QP8'].map(multipliers)
    df['QP9 Multiplier'] = df['QP9'].map(multipliers)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ipywidgets dropdown selection mapped to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727163/ipywidgets-dropdown-selection-mapped-to-dataframe)